# Receive Timeout Happen with my socket

Tags: c, sockets

Hi I try to write my own send and recv function for my application. Which has to handle 144  number of request per seconds in load. In Load mode my application faced recive timeout issue at the same time ( 5 request in 1 Lakh request). Here I have set 20 secs for timeout. pls tell me what is the problem with my code.

recvAll function :

```
int recvAll(int s, char *buf, int len, int timeout)
{
   fd_set fds;
   int n;
   struct timeval tv;
   FD_ZERO(&fds);
   FD_SET(s, &fds);
   tv.tv_sec = timeout;
   tv.tv_usec = 0;
   n = select(s+1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
   if (n == 0) return -2;
   if (n == -1) return -1;
   int retVal =recv(s, buf, len, 0);
   printf("received byes %d\n",retVal);
   buf[retVal+1]='\0';
   return retVal;
}
```

Function Call :

```
do
{
    if(0 >= (bytesRcvd =recvAll(sockfd, recvBuffer,1024,20)))
    {
        perror("Receive Timeout Happened");
        close(sockfd);
        return -1;
    }
    totalBytesRcvd += bytesRcvd;
}while(totalBytesRcvd < 1024);
```

Comment: Add error check for return values of `select`

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you're guessing. It could be any error at all. You're telling yourself it's a read timeout, but it could be EOS (`bytesRcvd == 0`) or some other error.

Comment: yes you are correct. server sends response but we didn't receive it. When server try to send response our application close the socket connection within those 1 seconds.

Comment: 1 second? 20 seconds? Make up your mind. 1 second is a ridiculously short timeout. Try something realistic.

Comment: 20 seconds only. but our connection closed within 1 seconds. This is what our problem with this code. I don't have any idea why this connection dropped with in 1 seconds even server has valid data as a response.

Comment: You don't have any idea what is happening at all. *Is* it a connection close? as you are now claiming? Or a timeout, as per your original question? Or some other error? You need to decide that first, and post it here. You need to trace the value of bytesRcvd, and the output of perror().

Comment: I traced at its 0 but server sends reponse with data for that particular request. This is the problem.

Comment: If it's zero, the server has closed the connection *instead* of sending any data. You don't seem to understand the TCP Sockets API.

Comment: I also don't understand why you're calling that method in a loop and throwing any data you do receive away. Please clarify.

Comment: The reason is suppose Application receives less than 1024 bytes then again it has to recv once again for that purpose only i put loop.

Comment: yeh me also thinking like that only but what is the problem na server sends the data at the time client socket has been closed. This is what my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Actually real problem is Interrupted signal has been caught (INTR) in load mode. So

```
do
{
    if(0 >= (bytesRcvd =recvAll(sockfd, recvBuffer,1024,20)))
    {
        if (errno == EINTR) continue;
        perror("Receive Timeout Happened");
        close(sockfd);
        return -1;
    }
    totalBytesRcvd += bytesRcvd;
}while(totalBytesRcvd < 1024);
```

This could be the answer for the above question.